# Dynamic create tr and add row number count

Tags: jquery, html

html to function

```
<tbody class="list">
       <tr>
          <td class="id">1</td>
          <td class="name">jason</td>
          <td class="number">2</td>
          <td class="edit"><button class="edit__item">Edit</button></td>
          <td class="remove"><button class="remove__item">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

function

```
function catchList() {
    var tr;
    $('#list tr').each(function(index, tr) {
        $('td:not(.id,.edit,.remove)', tr).each(function() {
            var textvalue = $(this).text();
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + textvalue + "</td>");
            $('.displayTable__list').append(tr);
        });
    });
}
```

display html

```
<div class="dataDisplay__list">
  <table class="teamList__displayTable">
    <thead>
     <tr class="displayTable__header">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="displayTable__list">

      //create those list at here 

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div><!-- end of dataDisplay__list -->
```

1st is to create the number count on row 1. 2. 3.

2nd how to i line it up probably using table ?

i a table which i have to get all inside tr value to a other table(display) , so i use the function to get all value and append them into the display table , but i have problem to line them up and i how do i create number on row ? my intention is like this.

**Name  Number**

1.jason    2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 
 $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".add-row").click(function(){

    var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
    //alert(rowCount);
                var name = $("#name").val();

                var email = $("#email").val();

                var markup = "<tr><td>" + rowCount + "</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>";

                $("table tbody").append(markup);

            });

            

            // Find and remove selected table rows

            $(".delete-row").click(function(){

                $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){

                    if($(this).is(":checked")){

                        $(this).parents("tr").remove();

                    }

                });

            });

        });
```

```css
table{

            width: 100%;

            margin: 20px 0;

            border-collapse: collapse;

        }

        table, th, td{

            border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;

        }

        table th, table td{

            padding: 5px;

            text-align: left;

        }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>jQuery Add / Remove Table Rows</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
    </head>

    <body>

        <form>

            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">

            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">

            <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">

        </form>

        <table id="myTable" class="myTable">

            <thead>

                <tr>

                    <th>No</th>
     
                    <th>Select</th>

                    <th>Name</th>

                    <th>Email</th>

                </tr>

            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <tr>

                    <td id="id" class="id">1</td>

                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="record"></td>

                    <td>Peter Parker</td>

                    <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>

                </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>

        <button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>

    </body> 

    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ur query is not clear. If setting row number is Ur issue, then it can be done by local var and incrementing it by one. Eg:

```
  function catchList(){
    var rowNum = 0;
    var tr;
    $('#list tr').each(function(index, tr) {
    rowNum++; //Then use it where ever needed!!!.
    $('td:not(.id,.edit,.remove)', tr).each(function() {
    var textvalue = $(this).text();
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + textvalue + "</td>");
    $('.displayTable__list').append(tr);
    });
    });
  }
```

Comment: is there any html can create the row number by it self ?

Comment: No, as per my knowledge, there is no html which auto attaches a number with itself